# How do I remove PWD from terminal?

Tags: command-line

How do I remove the PWD from the terminal? I'm not referring to the command but the automatic display next to my username@hostname. I would like it to work more like it does on other distros.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your home directory and edit `.bashrc` file. There you can find lines that look similar to this one:

> PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

Delete `\w` and current working directory will dissappear.

Comment: Thank you. The PS1 was a great keyword. It let me find this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: Make sure to delete `\w` from all the lines that match the `PS1` search within the `.bashrc` file

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of the prompt is based upon the value of the environment variable $PS1. To see it use:

```
    echo $PS1
```

You'll see something like this:

```
    \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

To remove your current working directory from your prompt, just remove the '\w' from the variable.

```
    export PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\$'
```

You'll get the prompt without the present working directory now.
To make the effect permanent, add that line to .bashrc file.